# How to get XDocument element values

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I've been coding a Minecraft Launcher. I'm saving user details to XML file with this code:

```
public static void SaveUserDetails(string username, string clientToken, 
  string accessToken, string UUID, int lengthOfPass)
{
    XDocument user = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XComment(String.Format("User details -- {0}", username)),
        new XElement("user",
            new XElement("username", username),
            new XElement("clientToken", clientToken),
            new XElement("accessToken", accessToken),
            new XElement("userUUID", UUID),
            new XElement("lengthOfPass", lengthOfPass)));
    SaveXDoc(user, Path.Combine(Variables.usersFolder, username + ".user"));
}
```

The end product looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--User details - - Ilan321-->
<user>
  <username>Ilan321</username>
  <clientToken>clienttoken</clientToken>
  <accessToken>accesstoken</accessToken>
  <userUUID>uuid</userUUID>
  <lengthOfPass>5</lengthOfPass>
</user>
```

Now, I want to read the values inside the elements. I do so with this code:

```
string details = null;
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(userFile);
var data = from item in doc.Descendants("user")
           select new
           {
               user = item.Element("username").Value,
               clientToken = item.Element("clientToken").Value,
               accessToken = item.Element("accessToken").Value,
               userUUID = item.Element("userUUID").Value,
               passLength = item.Element("lengthOfPass").Value
           };
foreach (var thing in data)
    details = thing.ToString(); // there is only one string
```

However, I feel as if this is very unprofessional (regarding the foreach that iterates through `var data`). Is there a way to quickly get all the values in string format instead of using a foreach? I tried converting `data` to string but it just made it into the type, not the content.

Comment: Are you looking for `allDetails = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,data);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below

```
foreach (var thing in data)
{
    details  = string.Format("user :{0}, clientToken: {1}",thing.user,thing.clientToken);
}
```

Or you better create new class for User and then you can [overide the ToString method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx) of it

```
public class User
{
    public string User  { get; set; }
    public string ClientToken { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string UserUUID { get; set; }
    public string PassLength { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("user :{0}, clientToken: {1}, AccessToken: {2},UserUUID :{3},  PassLength:{4}", User, ClientToken, AccessToken, UserUUID, PassLength);
    }

}
```

then

```
var data = from item in doc.Descendants("user")
            select new User
            {
                User = item.Element("username").Value,
                ClientToken = item.Element("clientToken").Value,
                AccessToken = item.Element("accessToken").Value,
                UserUUID = item.Element("userUUID").Value,
                PassLength = item.Element("lengthOfPass").Value
            };
details = data.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you expect one and only one node use [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the only element:

```
 details = data.First().ToString();
```

If element may not be present use `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this instead:

```
    var item = doc.Element("user");

    var data = new
    {
        user = item.Element("username").Value,
        clientToken = item.Element("clientToken").Value,
        accessToken = item.Element("accessToken").Value,
        userUUID = item.Element("userUUID").Value,
        passLength = item.Element("lengthOfPass").Value
    };

    details = data.ToString();
```

I get exactly the same output as you got with your code.